# i want to show datetimetype in symfony as interval

Tags: symfony

My application is for users to make an appointments with professionnals.
I have a professional and an appointment entities.
The professionnal has:

startAt: start of work in a given day

endAt: end of work at the same day

sessionTime: the duration of a session

For example:

`startAt=08:00
endAt=14:00
sessionTime=30mn`

In the reservation form i want to show only the available time for making an apppointment.

Following the above example, the available time is: 
- 8:00 
- 8:30 
- 9:00
- ...
- 13:00 
- 13:30

and remove from it the time were there is already an appointement.

How i can do that?

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: I didn't know where to star.

For now i only have the form.

`class RDVType extends AbstractType

{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('dateOf',DateTimeType::class,array('label'=>'Choisir la date de votre rendez-vous'))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Réserver'));
    }
}`

Comment: You should not use `DateTimeType` but `ChoiceType`. Then you must build an array of `choices` for this `ChoiceType`. I suggest you create a service `AvailableHoursProvider` which depends on `AppointmentRepository`, and which has a method that returns you the array of possible hours given `$startAt`, `$endAt`, `$sessionTime` and `$professionnal` (to get its appiointments). Then it's up to you to create the logic of your method, and import your service in your form.